# Are Shadowrun Returns saves compatible across different platforms?

Tags: shadowrun-returns

Now that shadowrun returns is available on both PC and mobile devices, can I transfer my save game from the PC over to, say, my android phone or vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible

As quoted from an admin on shadrowrun.com ([here](http://www.shadowrun.com/forums/discussion/comment/127793)), follow those steps :

> Step one: Connect your Android device to your computer, and ensure
>   it's acting as a media device, (this lets you access it via USB to
>   move files).
>
> Step two: Grab the desired saved game(s) from your machine,
>   (http://shadowrun-returns.wikispaces.com/Game+File+Locations+by+OS).
>
> Step three: Copy the file(s) to
>   Android/data/com.harebrainedschemes.shadowrun/files/Saves
>
> Step four: Load Shadowrun Returns and verify the saved game files
>   appear in "Load Game".
>
> Step five: Play!

This is just an assumption but I think it might work the other way arround.
However, I would backup files before overwritting anything. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: sweet!  thanks! I'll award the bounty tomorrow as soon as it allows me.