# Transfer save game Shadowrun Returns between Android Devices

Tags: android, shadowrun-returns

I know there have been several similar questions about saved games, but unfortunately they didn't answer this.  I have Shadowrun Returns on my phone (bad idea), and I'd like to get the saved game transferred to my tablet.  Both are Android.  I know [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/143098/are-shadowrun-returns-saves-compatible-across-different-platforms) answer says it should be under:

```
 Android/data/com.harebrainedschemes.shadowrun/files/Saves
```

However, I can't find the `com.harebrainedschemes.shadowrun` folder on my phone.  The saved game is on the load game menu, but I can't find it on the file system to transfer it.  What's the deal?  Where is the saved game files?  And unfortunately the wiki post linked in that question doesn't discuss Android's location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so apparently Android transfer program MTP on Mac doesn't show all of the files.  Once I decided to use Box.net to transfer the files I could see that directory.  They were also visible with programs like Astro File Manager.  So lesson here is Android MTP doesn't show Shadowrun's directories.